# Total number of settlers?

Tags: fallout-4

From my understanding your limited to 10 settlers + 1 extra settler per Charisma special point. This is PER SETTLEMENT. Including the bobble head that is a total of 22 settlers per settlement.

Does that mean someone could acquire a total of 22 settlers in each and every settlement of the game before reaching the upper maximum?

Comment: It's interesting that Google brings me to this question rather than the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fallout 4 wikia seems to confirm that:

> Each settlement has a default max population of 10 settlers plus each point of charisma your character has, totaling to a maximum of 20 settlers. This can however be further increased by wearing items that increase your charisma.

Also it has been reported, e.g. on reddit, that drugs and gear that affect charisma will increase your settlement's capacity way over 22.

I don't think there is any artificial cap. It's just 10+CH per settlement. If you up your charisma with e.g. an external application that modifies in-memory values, the number of settlers will probably grow. It's just a speculation, though.